# Pre trained dataset for Car damage detection

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, faster-rcnn

I'm making a Car Damage Detection model which would have 2 classes to detect upon. My dataset has a total of 300 images (out of which I'd be using some for testing), which are totally insufficient to train the model from scratch.

Can I use a pre-trained model to train my dataset and detect images based on the 2 classes, and if yes, then which one should be the best on my problem set?

P.S. - I would prefer to use Faster-RCNN on my dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any pre-trained image recognition model would probably work fine for this purpose. Once they learn main features, they fine tune really well. Take a look at [Keras Applications](https://keras.io/api/applications/) or [TensorFlow Hub](https://tfhub.dev/).

Answer (score 0):

For this task you should use any model pre-trained on the COCO's dataset.
We managed to get quite good results with only 80 images with a pre-trained MaskRCNN.